# ¿Porque no puedo intercambiar los valores de un arreglo usando punteros?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy programando en C++.
El código es el siguiente:
Lo que me interesa y a lo que va mi pregunta es que si la función "Intercambiar Elementos" está escrita correctamente? Estoy ocupando dos punteros y una variable auxiliar para realizar el intercambio.
La firma está correcta `void intercambiarElementos(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int *punt2);` y la función es

```
void intercambiarElementos(int arr[], int dim1, int *&p1, int *&punt2) {
    do {
        cout << "Cuantos números quieres agregar al arreglo? ";
        cin >> dim1;
    } while (dim1 <= 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        cout << "Digite el valor para la posición " << i << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    p1 = arr;               // Puntero apuntando al inicio del arreglo
    punt2 = &arr[dim1 - 1]; // Puntero apuntando al final del arreglo

    while (p1 < punt2) {
        int temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *punt2;
        *punt2 = temp;

        p1++;     // Incrementar p1
        punt2--;  // Decrementar punt2
    }

    cout << "El arreglo ordenado queda: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        cout << "[" << arr[i] << "]";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Quiero saber si están correctos los parámetro de esta función, es posible pasar un puntero por referencia para así poder ir actualizando los valores del puntero?.
Este es el error que me arroja al momento de compilar

```
C:\Users\MATAS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvDUcyx.o:punterosumaprod.cpp:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `intercambiarElementos(int*, int, int*, int*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Qué puede ser?.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void intercambiarElementos(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int *punt2);
int llenarF(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int suma);
int llenarFproduct(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int producto);

int main() {
    int opsalir, dim1 = 0;
    int arr[100]; // Tamaño máximo del arreglo, puedes ajustarlo según tus necesidades

    do {
        cout << "1. Sumar\n2. Producto\n3. Intercambiar los valores de dos arreglos\n4. Salir\n";
        cout << "Ingrese una opción: ";
        cin >> opsalir;

        int *p1, *punt2; // Creación de punteros

        switch (opsalir) {
            case 1: {
                cout << "¿Cuántos números quieres sumar? ";
                cin >> dim1;

                int suma = 0;
                suma = llenarF(arr, dim1, p1, suma);

                cout << "La suma es: " << suma << endl;
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                cout << "¿Cuántos números quieres multiplicar? ";
                cin >> dim1;

                int producto = 1;
                producto = llenarFproduct(arr, dim1, p1, producto);

                cout << "El producto es: " << producto << endl;
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                intercambiarElementos(arr, dim1, p1, punt2);
                break;
            }

            case 4: {
                return 0;
            }

            default: {
                cout << "Opción inválida. Por favor, ingrese una opción válida." << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (opsalir != 4);

    return 0;
}

void intercambiarElementos(int arr[], int dim1, int *&p1, int *&punt2) {
    do {
        cout << "Cuantos números quieres agregar al arreglo? ";
        cin >> dim1;
    } while (dim1 <= 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        cout << "Digite el valor para la posición " << i << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    p1 = arr;               // Puntero apuntando al inicio del arreglo
    punt2 = &arr[dim1 - 1]; // Puntero apuntando al final del arreglo

    while (p1 < punt2) {
        int temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *punt2;
        *punt2 = temp;

        p1++;     // Incrementar p1
        punt2--;  // Decrementar punt2
    }

    cout << "El arreglo ordenado queda: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        cout << "[" << arr[i] << "]";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int llenarF(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int suma) {
    p1 = arr; // p1 apunta al inicio del arreglo

    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        cout << "Digite el número " << i + 1 << " a sumar: ";
        cin >> arr[i];

        *p1 = arr[i];
        suma += *p1;

        p1++; // Apuntar a la siguiente posición
    }

    return suma;
}

int llenarFproduct(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int producto) {
    p1 = arr; // p1 apunta al inicio del arreglo

    for (int j = 0; j < dim1; j++) {
        cout << "Digite el número " << j + 1 << " a multiplicar: ";
        cin >> arr[j];

        *p1 = arr[j];
        producto *= *p1;

        p1++;
    }

    return producto;
}
```

Comment: ¿El código compila y funciona como debería? Si es así, entonces la pregunta del título ya está respondida. Sé más claro respecto a las demás preguntas.

Comment: @Mateo He actualizado el post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón del error es que la declaración de tu función no coincide con la definición.

Tu declaración:

```
void intercambiarElementos(int arr[], int dim1, int *p1, int *punt2);
```

Tu definición:

```
void intercambiarElementos(int arr[], int dim1, int *&p1, int *&punt2);
```

Nota que a los 2 últimos parámetros les falta el `&`.